# Infinispan Cache Indexing- org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper\write.lock

Tags: indexing, infinispan

I am using Infinispan 8.2.2 in client-server mode (2 nodes 1 cluster), use replicated cache with indexing configuration as below. Data in getting indexed as well. I use a .proto file to map to my object and index some of the fields in the object as well. Whenever I writes to cache for each row write, below exception occurs. Could you please help.

**Configuration**

```
`<replicated-cache name="tickets-cache" mode="ASYNC" start="EAGER"> 
    <indexing index="ALL">
   property name="default.indexmanager">near-real-time</property
<property name="lucene_version">LUCENE_CURRENT</property>
 <property name="default.chunk_size">128000</property>
 </indexing>                            
  <locking acquire-timeout="60000"/>
  <expiration lifespan="43200000"/>                 
</replicated-cache>`
```

**Exception**

```
            Exception
            2016-08-04 20:59:08,318 ERROR [org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler] (Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper) HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\WorkSpace\Softwares\infinispan-server-8.2.2.Final\org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper\write.lock
            Primary Failure:
              Entity org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper  Id A:SgRCQUcx  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.UpdateLuceneWork
            : org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\WorkSpace\Softwares\infinispan-server-8.2.2.Final\org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper\write.lock
              at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
              at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
              at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
              at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:123)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:89)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:117)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:203)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:80)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:46)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:162)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:148)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


            2016-08-04 20:59:08,320 ERROR [org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask] (Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper) HSEARCH000072: Couldn't open the IndexWriter because of previous error: operation skipped, index ouf of sync!
            2016-08-04 20:59:55,255 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (remote-thread--p2-t13) DGISPN0001: Started ___event_log_cache cache from clustered container
            2016-08-04 20:59:55,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (remote-thread--p2-t13) DGISPN0001: Started ___query_cache cache from clustered container
            2016-08-04 21:00:12,036 ERROR [org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler] (Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper) HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\WorkSpace\Softwares\infinispan-server-8.2.2.Final\org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper\write.lock
            Primary Failure:
              Entity org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper  Id A:SgRCQUcw  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.UpdateLuceneWork
            : org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: D:\WorkSpace\Softwares\infinispan-server-8.2.2.Final\org.infinispan.query.remote.impl.indexing.ProtobufValueWrapper\write.lock
              at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118)
              at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
              at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
              at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:123)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:89)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:117)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:203)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:80)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:46)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:162)
              at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:148)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```